# Will Samsung Galaxy Buds work with iPod Nano Gen 7?

Tags: bluetooth, ipod-nano

From what I can gather, the iPod Nano (7th Gen) requires true Bluetooth connectivity / synchronization for wireless headphones. This means (as per their product page) that AirPods won't actually work with the iPod Nano.

However, from what I understand the Samsung Galaxy Buds **are** true Bluetooth and *should* sync up with iPod Nanos. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Samsung Galaxy Buds work with the iPod Nano Gen 7. AirPods 1 & 2 also work just fine with the Nano Gen 7. I've already personally tried them and they work great.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post.